# Hybrid Graphics

Tags: arch-linux, power-management, laptop, gpu

I recently installed Arch Linux. I also have Windows 10. But when loaded into Arch my battery drains much faster (4xtimes faster than windows). I also see my laptop gets much heat.I did some search and I found that linux support to hybrid cards are experimental. So I need to disable my Nvidia GPU when loaded into Arch and only use Intel Graphics 620. And I also need a power management tool so every configuration is ideal to save battery to get same performance as Windows 10. I like Linux Community , Once I get configured everything in Linux I'l ditch windows. So help me here guys,!My system Configuration

```
Operating System: Arch Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.82.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.10.39-1-lts
OS Type: 64-bit
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Memory: 7.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
```

Comment: Please ask here as well: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov I asked there too, Will I get a answer to this question? I looked some question on graphics here but with no answer,! I already went through a lot  installing Arch. I thought somebody could help, Is it worth waiting,? Or I should go for documentation about graphics?